# Spring and Jackson ObjectMapper not working with custom Filter

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am using Spring 3.2.1 and Jackson 2.

I have the following Spring configuration file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean 
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">

            <property name="objectMapper" ref="myObjectMapper" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
<bean
    name="myObjectMapper"
    class="org.me.reference.util.MyObjectMapper" />
```

My custom ObjectMapper looks like this:

```
public class MyObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    /**
     * A default version UID to use when serializing an instance of this class.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyObjectMapper() {
        setFilters(
            (new SimpleFilterProvider())
                .addFilter(
                    "CustomJacksonFilter",
                    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("password"));
    }
}
```

My domain object looks like this:

```
@JsonFilter("CustomJacksonFilter")
public class User {
    /**
     * The JSON key for the user's user-name.
     */
    public static final String JSON_KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    /**
     * The JSON key for the user's password.
     */
    public static final String JSON_KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    /**
     * The user's user-name.
     */
    @JsonProperty(JSON_KEY_USERNAME)
    private final String username;
    /**
     * The user's password.
     */
    @JsonProperty(JSON_KEY_PASSWORD)
    private final String password;

    ...
}
```

Basically, I want to be sure that the password is not automatically serialized whenever I return a User object. I feel like this should work, however I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not resolve BeanPropertyFilter with id 'CustomJacksonFilter'; no FilterProvider configured
```

I have tried many variants of the above configuration with no success. I have investigated using a View, but then I need to annotate **everything** except the one field that I don't want to serialize, which is too cumbersome.

Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you,

John

**EDIT:**

Full stack trace:

```
SEVERE: The server threw an unexpected exception.
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mongojack.MongoJsonMappingException: Error mapping BSON to POJOs
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:932)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.me.reference.filter.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.me.reference.filter.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.mongojack.MongoJsonMappingException: Error mapping BSON to POJOs
    at org.mongojack.JacksonDBCollection.convertToDbObject(JacksonDBCollection.java:1643)
    at org.mongojack.JacksonDBCollection.insert(JacksonDBCollection.java:239)
    at org.me.reference.data.mongodb.MongoUserBin.createUser(MongoUserBin.java:86)
    at org.me.reference.request.UserRegistrationRequest.service(UserRegistrationRequest.java:169)
    at org.me.reference.servlet.Version1.handleRequest(Version1.java:1454)
    at org.me.reference.servlet.Version1.registerUser(Version1.java:1117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not resolve BeanPropertyFilter with id 'MeJacksonFilter'; no FilterProvider configured
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.findFilter(BeanSerializerBase.java:630)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFieldsFiltered(BeanSerializerBase.java:590)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:141)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:120)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:457)
    at org.mongojack.JacksonDBCollection.convertToDbObject(JacksonDBCollection.java:1641)
    ... 44 more
```

Comment: Take a look at the two answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382094/jsonfilter-throws-jsonmappingexception-can-not-resolve-beanpropertyfilter

Comment: Thank you, but those didn't appear to work. I tried the `filterProvider.setFailOnUnknownId(false);`, which seemed promising, but it didn't appear to work. As far as getting the writer, I leave all of that up to Spring.

Comment: Please post your full stacktrace.

Comment: Added the full stack trace. I think I see the problem now. It's the MongoJack FilterProvider that needs to not fail on unknown IDs.

Comment: I just tried the `ObjectMapper` on its own and it works for me. I suggest you debug by putting a breakpoint in the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. Seems it's using another Mapper.

Comment: That was it. I needed to modify MongoJack to use a custom ObjectMapper that was set to not fail on unknown IDs. If you want to create a response to that effect, I will give you the checkmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ObjectMapper` implementation works fine and provides a `FilterProvider`, but looking at your exception's stack trace, it doesn't look like the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` you registered is being called for the serialization. You must therefore be serializing with a different `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: It was the MongoJack ObjectMapper that was doing the (de)serialization on the DB side, not the HTTP side. Thanks!