# How to filter attributes from JSON response in spring?

Tags: json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I have a controller like the following,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "rest/v1/tester")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<SampleResults> search(@ModelAttribute("criteria")SampleCriteria criteria) throws Exception {
            SampleResults sampleResults = sampleService.search(criteria);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(sampleResults, OK);
    }

}
```

I have another controller like so,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "rest/v1/second")
public class SecondTestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<SampleResults> search(@ModelAttribute("criteria")SampleCriteria criteria) throws Exception {
            SampleResults sampleResults = secondsampleService.search(criteria);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(sampleResults, OK);
    }

}
```

The structure of my result is as follows:

```
public class SampleResults extends Results<SearchSummary, Sample> {
}
```

This extends from the result class:

```
public class Results<SUMMARY,RESULTS> {
    private SUMMARY summary;
    private List<RESULTS> results;

    /*Constructors, getters and setters*/
}
```

Now the model that I am going to set into the results field is,

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = SampleImpl.class)
public interface Sample {

    Long getId();
    void setId(Long id);

    String getName();
    void setName(String name);

    int getAge();
    void setAge(int age);

}

public class SampleImpl implements Sample {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    /* Getters and Setters */

}
```

Now for the TestController mentioned above, I would like to display all the fields in the json response, whereas in the SecondTestController I would like to mask (not show) the age attribute in the json response. How can I achieve this in spring. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8189201/6565719) helps?

Comment: Take a look at this realy good article https://samkruglov.wordpress.com/2018/01/07/json-filtering-with-spring/

Answer (score 4):

I think the most simple way to do that is to use Jackson `@JsonFilter` if you want it dynamic.

For instance, here could be an exemple with Spring Boot :

Your document :

```
@JsonFilter("myFilter")
class Document {
   private field1;
   private field2;
}
```

Modify your default configured HttpMessageConverter :

```
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        for(HttpMessageConverter<?> converter: converters) {
            if(converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                ObjectMapper mapper = ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)converter).getObjectMapper();
                mapper.setFilterProvider(new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAll()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This Filter will serialize all by default. This step is mandatory, if you don't specify it, you will have an exception coming that he does not know `myFilter` when your controller will try to generate an object response.

Then, in you controller, here is your regular endpoint that serialize all field (using the previously declared filter):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "path/document", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Document getDocumentWithAllFields() {
   return new Document("val1","val2");
} 
//result : {"field1":"val1","field2":"val2"}
```

And now, the endpoint to have the same object with only some fields serialized :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "path/document", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public MappingJacksonValue getDocumentWithSomeFields(@RequestParam String[] fields) {
    MappingJacksonValue wrapper = new MappingJacksonValue(new Document("val1","val2"));
    FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myFilter", 
         SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(fields)); 
    wrapper.setFilters(filterProvider);
    return wrapper;
} 
//result : {"field1":"val1"} (with 'fields' being a coma separated list, containing here just "field1"
```

Comment: seems its even easier in spring 4.2+, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36488056/438727

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [`@JsonView`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html)?

It is [supported by Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) and allows you to filter fields depending on the context of serialization.

First define your views:

```java
public class View {     

    interface SampleView { }  
    interface SampleViewWithAge extends SampleView { }   
}
```

Then annotate your fields using the desired view:

```java
public class SampleImpl implements Sample { 

    @JsonView(View.SampleView.class)
    private Long id; 

    @JsonView(View.SampleView.class)
    private String name; 

    @JsonView(View.SampleViewWithAge.class)
    private int age;

    // Getters and setters
 }
```

Finally annotate your handlers to use a view when serializing the response:

```java
@JsonView(View.SampleView.class) 
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public ResponseEntity<SampleResults> search() {
    ... 
}

@JsonView(View.SampleViewWithAge.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public ResponseEntity<SampleResults> searchWithAge() {
    ... 
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach but I keep getting an exception stating:
"message":"500:Exception: ","logger_name":"com.cdk.dmg.services.sample.exceptions.APIExceptionHandler","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"ERROR","stack_trace":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Can not resolve PropertyFilter with id 'DynamicFieldFilter'; no FilterProvider configured; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not resolve PropertyFilter with id 'DynamicFieldFilter';

Answer (score 0):

Override toString method in your modal class with required fields and convert it to json explicitly as below in your second controller method.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
//get yourObject

ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(yourObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

public class BeanFilterCustom {

```
public Object filterBean(Object object,String someBeanFilter)  {

    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("","");
    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
            .addFilter(someBeanFilter, filter);
    MappingJacksonValue mapping = new MappingJacksonValue(object);
    mapping.setFilters(filters);
    return mapping.getValue();
}
```

}

Comment: Object is any DTO and someBeanFilter is bean property