# How to design Rest API with uri having multivalue parameter and change json response as per user input

Tags: java, rest, api-design

In one of the interview I was asked below question

URI student/1

suppose 1 is Roll number of the student and we get a response like

{
"sname" : "abc",
"sBloodGroup" : "o pos",
"age" : "30",
"some extra fileds" : "xyz",
...
...
}

Now task is to create a rest api where user can give multivalue parameter and response should have only required fields as requested.

URL : student/1?fieldName=sname,age
{
sname : "abc"
age : "30"
}

how can we design such problem?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314735/how-to-return-a-partial-json-response-using-java

Answer (score -1):

If you are using noSql DB like MongoDB you can use the fieldname as projections and the same document you can parse to json and return back in api response.

like:

db.student.find({id:1},{_id:0,sname:1,age:1})

it will return you only the required json